# Adding tcpdump to android app

Tags: java, android, tcpdump

Can I just store the tcpdump-arm file in an assets folder in my app so that when I eventually release the app the user would not have to do get it themselves?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to say probably not. You'll notice that any app that makes use of tcpdump requires root. Now, whether that is true for any binary used by an app, or just because of what tcpdump is accessing, I'm not sure.

However, I believe that the Shark for Root app has a tcpdump implementation bundled with it, but I would guess that they used the NDK for that. That may be worth looking into though, see if you can use the tcpdump-arm source code in your app using NDK.